# Test classes do not see the classes under test when unit testing for Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

I am trying to write unit tests in C# for the scripts that need to run inside Unity3D, later. My C# scripts are in the folder "Assets/Scripts" of the Unity project.

I am using **Unity version 2019.1.0f2** with **Visual Studio Community for Mac V8.0.5 (build 9)**, under **Mac OS X version 10.14.4**.

Unity has a test runner window that I used: `Window > General > Test runner`. Inside that test runner window, I clicked on "Play mode" and on "Create Playmode Test Assembly Folder". Unity created a folder called "Tests" for me in which I am supposed to put my tests. So far, so good.

Now here is the problem:

**My test code cannot see the classes under test that are in the parent folder of that test folder!**

This is the folder hierarchy:

```
  Assets
    Scripts
      MyFirstScript.cs
      Tests
        MyTestScript.cs
        Tests.asmdef
```

When I double-click on MyTestScript.cs, Visual Studio opens the solution and the source file OK. Now, I am trying to write

```
    var x = new MyFirstScript();
```

and the compiler complains "The type or namespace name 'MyFirstScript' could not be found".

It seems as if the classes in the Scripts folder are completely unknown inside the classes that are in the Tests folder.

This is MyFirstScript.cs:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class MyFirstScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is MyTestScript.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;

namespace Tests
{
    public class MyTestScript
    {
        // A Test behaves as an ordinary method
        [Test]
        public void MyTestScriptSimplePasses()
        {
            var x = new MyFirstScript(); // problem occurs HERE!

            // Use the Assert class to test conditions
        }

        // A UnityTest behaves like a coroutine in Play Mode. In Edit Mode you can use
        // `yield return null;` to skip a frame.
        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator MyTestScriptWithEnumeratorPasses()
        {
            // Use the Assert class to test conditions.
            // Use yield to skip a frame.
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that I could use the class MyFirstScript in my test code (MyTestScript). What can I do?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I did not see this when searching for a solution. This was perfect, thank you very much, @Hellium

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MonoBehaviourTest section of [this manual page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlaymodeTestFramework.html).

Note that with Unity, it's almost never a good idea to call 'new' on a MonoBehaviour-derived object.  You almost always want to instantiate it by calling AddComponent() on a GameObject.

Comment: Thanks, Louis, for the hint!

Comment: Link appears to be broken.